# Can't get Terraform instance IP address after create

Tags: terraform, vultr

Utilizng Vultr's terraform provider, I'm creating a few instances of machines.
All is great, except I'm now trying to create cloudflare records (subdomains pointing to each new machine respectively) for these machines that are being spawned by terraform.

vultr_instance

```
resource "vultr_instance" "test" {
  label              = "test"
  region = "dfw"
  plan = "vc2-2c-4gb"
  os_id             = "413" # ubuntu 20.10
  # https://api.vultr.com/v1/os/list
  hostname          = "test"
}
```

dns record

```
  zone_id = var.cloudflare_zone_id
  name    = "test"
  #value   = "192.168.0.11"
  value = test.main_ip
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = 3600
}
```

Per the vultr provider docs, it exports main_ip which is the ip of the machine after being spawned, however terraform won't let me simply call main_ip as a variable

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on vultr.tf line 33, in resource "cloudflare_record" "test_dns":
  33:   value = test.main_ip

A managed resource "test" "main_ip" has not been declared in the root
module.
```

[main_ip in vultr provider docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/vultr/vultr/latest/docs/resources/instance#main_ip)

Trying to get this into 1 tf file if possible, however anyway to get this to work would be amazing

Comment: You're missing the resource type in your reference, it should be `vultr_instance.test.main_ip`.

Comment: See https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/blocks/resources/behavior.html#accessing-resource-attributes

Comment: @Adrian yeeeeeeppp that did it, thanks a bunch!